# Why is there a tower of glass in my lake?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While exploring I've found a tower of glass blocks coming out of a lake in Minecraft.

[image: tower of glass blocks out from a lake]

As far as I can tell they go up to the top limit of the world.

It also goes down in to the ground, as you can see by this quick test dig on the lake bed:

[image: they also seem to go down in to the water bed]

Why is it there?
Bug or feature?
Does it mean anything specific?
etc

---

*For Info:*
I'm using Beta 1.9 Prerelease 3, and have only ever used 1.9pre3 (I'm a very new MC player, and thought I'd start with the "latest" version), so this can't be an artifact from map generated by the old version, for example.

Also I have no mods, tweaks, etc in place - the game is completely stock.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In 1.9 pre-3 [some debug tools have been left on](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history/Development_versions). One of which is glass towers coming out of the top of strongholds:

> Debug Features:
>
> - 1x1 glass pillars to spot Strongholds

If you follow this glass spire down, you should hit a stronghold.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. Shame I've found one a slightly cheaty way, but time to setup a base and get exploring a stronghold.